# [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" checks all the checkbox for angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive form and when I assigning [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" for the checkbox then it checks all the checkboxes by default.

Below is my input:

```
<input value="{{role.roleName}}" [(ngModel)]="role.roleId" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="checkbox" (change)="validateUserRole(role, $event,role.roleName)" [checked]="role.checked">
```

Also, tried with **name** attribute.

Comment: If you were using reactive forms, you wouldn't use ngModel. In fact, nothing in your code indicates that you are using reactive forms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using template driven forms. You are incorrectly binding to the properties of the input. You need to drop `value="{{role.roleName}}"` and `[checked]="role.checked"` bindings and change `[(ngModel)]` binding.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="role.checked" 
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
       type="checkbox" 
       (change)="validateUserRole(role, $event,role.roleName)">
```